# Android Studio documentation

Tags: android-studio

I install Android Studio on windows 10 (I had the same problem on windows 8.1) and when I click on some classes from documentation it opens the documentation on browser. For example I have

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

and I open the pop up window with documentation for Menu. After that there is highlighted word Menu in this documention and I click it. I expect to open me again the documentation for Menu in this pop up, but instead of this it opens me the documentation in browser (it is exactly like android.developers site, but it doesn't open it from the site - it use my local documentation - the link is file:///E:/AndroidSDK/docs/reference/android/view/Menu.html ). This doesn't happens with every class, but it happens very often. So is there a way to make it to load documentation in the pop up, because it is really anoying. I hope that I explain my problem in details and clearly.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So, I decided a problem. In SDK Manager I deleted "Documentation for android SDK". And now it corectly works and online (with turned ON Internet), and offline.

1. Open SDK Manager: Tools > Android > SDK Manager.
2. Turn off flag "Documentation for android SDK".
3. Apply changes.